# Problema con instancias de Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, instancias

Estoy aprendiendo Tkinter, manejo Python hace muchos años, pero me surgió un inconveniente.

Estoy creando un formulario con tkinter, entonces hago la instancia de una ventana y luego defino algunas variables `StringVar()`, no tengo problema con eso, todo se ejecuta correctamente.

```py
from tkinter import *

ventana = Tk()

dato_nombre = StringVar() 
dato_apellido = StringVar() 
resultado_nombre_completo = StringVar()
```

Pero ordenando un poco el código moví la instancia de la ventana después de las variables `StringVar()`

```py
from tkinter import *

dato_nombre = StringVar() 
dato_apellido = StringVar() 
resultado_nombre_completo = StringVar()

ventana = Tk()
```

Y me manda un error
**`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'`**

No entiendo el porqué del error, porque no estoy llamando a la instancia `ventana` con la función `StringVar()`.

**¿Porqué pasa esto?**

Answer (score 2):

Usted tenía el código bien hasta que puso las variables antes de la creación de la instancia de clase, por lo cual, `dato_nombre = tk.StringVar()`, `dato_apellido = tk.StringVar()`, `resultado_nombre_completo = tk.StringVar()`, no pueden definirse sin un padre o instancia de clase, o que estén fuera del bucle inicial. No puede crear una variable como lo es `tk.StringVar()` hasta después de que se haya creado la ventana raíz.

**Este código es correcto:**

```
import tkinter as tk

ventana = tk.Tk()

dato_nombre = tk.StringVar() 
dato_apellido = tk.StringVar() 
resultado_nombre_completo = tk.StringVar()

ventana.mainloop()
```

> Nótese que importar la librería Tkinter con comodín `(*)` no es
> correcto, también en su código olvido la rutina o bucle inicial
> `mainloop()`, son cosas básicas del funcionamiento de Tkinter.

Comment: Si, bueno el * nunca lo uso, solo lo puse como ejemplo, y obviamente se que va un mainloop, si no como cargo la ventana, pero traté de reducir el código hasta lo más escencial para que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: La explicación de definir las variables antes o después que me das es la misma que yo di. Claro que se cual es el código correcto y cual es el incorrecto, mi pregunta es ¿Porque? . Lo único con lo que me voy a quedar de tu explicación es que "es un bucle". Sigo sin entender porque.

Comment: Usted no está entiendo bien, cuando usted crea una **instancia de clase**, al utilizar variables **debe** tener un padre o `root` como en programación funcional. Por lo que veo usted no maneja bien los fundamentos básicos no solo de Tkinter si no de la programación, es como si usted resuelve una ecuación sin definir las variables (sea x o y), esto es lo más lógico de mundo por lo cual esta es la respuesta. Por ejemplo, `root` solo es una variable para definir la creación de las ventanas, así que si no define `root`, no hay ventana. Las variables en cualquier situación deben ir antes.

Comment: Sobre el comentario de que no es correcto llamar a tkinter con comodín(*), en TkDocs.com opinan esto: "Our program starts by incorporating Tk.

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
These two lines tell Python that our program needs two modules. The first, tkinter, is the standard binding to Tk. When imported, it loads the Tk library on your system. The second, ttk, is a submodule of tkinter. It implements Python's binding to the newer "themed widgets" that were added to Tk in 8.5."